# I can't get setInterval() to work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

i have an algorithm that generates permutations of a given word. I'm trying to use `setInterval()` to generate the next permutation but the function runs only once! I can't figure out why. I don't get any error messages.
Here is my code

```
var splitted;
var t;
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function() {
    //change Start to Stop and change button id
    $('#SubmitBtn').attr('id','StopBtn').attr('value','Stop');
    //and add click event to it
    $('#StopBtn').click(function() {
        clearInterval(t);
        $('#StopBtn').attr('value','Submit');
        $('StopBtn').attr('id','SubmitBtn');
    });
    if ($('#AnagramTxtArea').val().length>0)
            $('#AnagramTxtArea').text('');
    var inputTxt = $('#anagram').val();
    splitted = inputTxt.split("");
    splitted.sort(); //first sort the array in order to generate permutations
    $('#AnagramTxtArea').append(splitted.join("") + " ");
    t= setInterval(GeneratePermutation(),10);
});
 });

 var AnagramObj = new Anagram();
 function GeneratePermutation() {
        splitted = AnagramObj.NextPermutation(splitted);
        if (splitted!=null)
            $('#AnagramTxtArea').append(splitted.join("") + " ");       
        else  
            $('#StopBtn').click();

    }
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<input id="anagram" type="text" placeholder="Insert your text here" maxlength="80"/>                    <br />
<input id="SubmitBtn" type="submit" value="submit" />
<br />
<textarea id="AnagramTxtArea" readonly="readonly"></textarea>

</div>
```

EDIT:
Yet, another problem:

When calling $('#StopBtn').click() code continues to execute after existing the click event function. So i'm in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass the function object itself to `setInterval()`, not the result of a call to the function:

```
t = setInterval(GeneratePermutation,10);
                                // ^ No parentheses
```

**EDIT:** On your second question, what you can do is check whether the interval is running. If it is, then cancel it:

```
var splitted;
var t;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function() {
    if (t !== undefined) { //interval is already running
        clearInterval(t);
        t = undefined;
        $('#SubmitBtn').attr('value','Submit');
    } else {
        //change Start to Stop
        $('#SubmitBtn').attr('value','Stop');
        if ($('#AnagramTxtArea').val().length>0)
                $('#AnagramTxtArea').text('');
        var inputTxt = $('#anagram').val();
        splitted = inputTxt.split("");
        splitted.sort(); //first sort the array in order to generate permutations
        $('#AnagramTxtArea').append(splitted.join("") + " ");
        t = setInterval(GeneratePermutation,10);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @DanDinu: I updated my answer with a solution to your second problem.

Comment: works great but i can't really understand why. You're changing the button id to StopBtn and call $('#StopBtn').click() from GeneratePermtation(). Why does it still fire the SubmitBtn.click()? It's another id..

Comment: @DanDinu: While it's a different ID, it's still the same element. The click handler is bound to the element.

Comment: I see, but then(by my logic) i should't change the id, just the text value from Submit to Send and viceversa. It doesn't work though...

Comment: @DanDinu: Just changing the text is fine. I am not sure why it isn't working for you. Perhaps double check that you replaced all occurrences of the original IDs with the new one.

Answer (score 4):

Here you actually execute `GeneratePermutation()` at the time you call setInterval():

```
t = setInterval(GeneratePermutation(),10);
```

You have to pass a function to setInterval(). Do this instead:

```
t = setInterval(GeneratePermutation, 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must pass in the function name or an anonymous function as the first argument for setInterval. See MDN reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

```
t = setInterval(GeneratePermutation,10);
```

or

```
t = setInterval(function() { /* code */ }, 10);
```

proper syntax for setInterval:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

where

- intervalID is a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval().
- func is the function you want to be called repeatedly. code in the
- alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to be executed
  repeatedly. (Using this syntax is not recommended for the same
  reasons as using eval()) delay is the number of milliseconds
  (thousandths of a second) that the setInterval() function should wait
  before each call to func. As with setTimeout, there is a minimum
  delay enforced.

**Edit:**
This could be a problem, assuming you are trying to fire a click.

```
function GeneratePermutation() {
        splitted = AnagramObj.NextPermutation(splitted);
        if (splitted!=null)
            $('#AnagramTxtArea').append(splitted.join("") + " ");       
        else  
            //$('#StopBtn').click();
            // should be
            $('#StopBtn').trigger('click');

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$('#StopBtn').click()` is firing?  Throw an `alert()` or `console.log()` in the function. See my edit as well

Comment: yes, it's firing. i used breakpoints in chrome, but after it gets to the end of the click function code continues to execute